# Status Bar and Navigation Bar Color for Lower Version Android Not Working

Tags: android

I trying to implement Status Bar Color and Navigation  Bar Color in My app, as it is given here

[App Compact 21](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)

and here [Maintaining Copatibility](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html)

```
 <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/status_bar</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/status_bar</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/status_bar</item>
    </style>
```

However the color of status bar is still black. Can any one tell me why status bar color is not changing. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the status bar color has been implemented in AppCompat yet. I faced the exact problem and after days of online research i came to this conclusion and reversed back to SystemBarTint lib (https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint)  for changing the status bar color.